# Aws database error php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have connected my appication with aws rds with the script below:

```php
function db_connect() {
   $result = new mysqli($_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'], $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME'], $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD'], $_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME'], $_SERVER['RDS_PORT']);
   if (!$result) {
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to database server');
   } else {
     return $result;
   }
}
```

It was working fine then i had to change it due to a new feature which someone else wrote the code for:

```
$dbOptions = array(
    'db_host' => 'RDS_HOSTNAME',
    'db_user' => 'RDS_USERNAME',
    'db_pass' => 'RDS_PASSWORD',
    'db_name' => 'RDS_DB_NAME'
);
```

I didn't add the port because he didn't and i never connected to database with an array and key like this, how do i go about adding port like at what position.

Comment: you need to find the code that uses the array varaibles.

Comment: Edited formatting. The question itself could be a bit more clearer.

Answer (score -1):

I was forgetting the $_SERVER variable:

```
$dbOptions = array(
'db_host' => $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
'db_user' => $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME'],
'db_pass' => $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD'],
'db_name' => $_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME']
```

);